# How to quickly compare string against lots of predefined strings?

Tags: c++, performance

I need to quickly compare requested path against predefined constants, like this:

```c
if (path == "/admin")
    ...
else if (path == "/something-else")
    ...
else if (path == "/something-else2")
else
    ...
```

However, the list is very huge.  The problem here is speed. I need to do it very quickly.
How would you go about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make it an integer comparison.** Use a hash function, which makes an integer from your string. Integers are a lot quicker in comparing. Then just use a static lookup table or a switch to pick quickly the desired action.

One very good and fast hash function is [MurmurHash2](http://smhasher.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MurmurHash2.cpp), it also has a low collision rate.
Offline generate values for your pathes, then compare the path against them:

```c
switch (MurmurHash2(path.c_str(), path.size(), MAGIC_SEED_CONSTANT)
{
    case 0xFA01FDF1: /* /admin */
        ...
        break;
    case 0xCC040A12: /* /something-else */
        ...
        break;
    case 0xBDF450A3: /* /something-else2 */
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

Comment: If you've got N words of average M characters, I don't care how fast the hash function is, it's going to have to look at every character of the input key: O(M). Then your switch statement is going to do an IF-ladder, O(N), so overall it is O(N). My answer takes O(M), without the O(N), and it has very small proportional constant.

Answer (score 2):

If your predefined strings are all known at runtime, you can try using boost::spirit.  It builds the compile time strings into a trie and then uses that to parse.  On a successful match, it will perform an associated semantic action.  I think the Roman Numeral example may be a close fit for this sort of requirement.

If your predefined strings are not known at runtime, then a runtime built trie could be tried.  I did something similar with my example code at my [Keyword Matching Blog Entry](http://blog.raymond.burkholder.net/index.php?/archives/371-Keyword-Matching-non-text-streams.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Raymond's answer, but without using Boost.

Suppose your strings are, as given in advance. AA, AB, BA, BB.
You can write a little program to sort the list, and then recursively print out a nested switch statement looking like this, which is a hard-coded trie:

```
switch(path[0]){
  break; case 'A': switch(path[1]){
    break; case 'A': switch(path[2]){
      break; case '\0':; // "AA" found
      break; default:
        // no match
    }
    break; case 'B': switch(path[2]){
      break; case '\0':; // "AB" found
      break; default:
        // no match
    }
    break; default:
      // no match
  }
  break; case 'B': switch(path[1]){
    break; case 'A': switch(path[2]){
      break; case '\0':; // "BA" found
      break; default:
        // no match
    }
    break; case 'B': switch(path[2]){
      break; case '\0':; // "BB" found
      break; default:
        // no match
    }
    break; default:
      // no match
  }
  break; default:
    // no match
}
```

Then copy/include that nested switch statement into the main program.

It will be hard to beat that code, for speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your string literals of path names as std::set and use its method find ti determine whether a given path is present in the set.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach would be to concatenate all the strings into one string and use one call to std::string::find to see if the input has a match anywhere within.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to store all the path to compare in a sorted `vector` then do a `std::lower_bound` to find the occurrence.
 You can then do a switch on a an index which is less cryptic values than a hash key.